# Run an ephemeral Spring Boot app out of main class or a startup listener?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Java 8 and Spring Boot 2.x here. I've used Spring Boot for the last several years to write web apps and RESTful web services alike, and I absolutely love it.

I now have a need to write a bunch of short-lived (non-service/daemon) apps that need to start up, do some work, and shut down. Exact length of runtime will vary depending on workload but never more than ~10 minutes. Although they do *not* involve hosting any server-side HTTP code (REST endpoints, controllers, etc.) like an traditional web app/service does, they do still need:

- Dependency injection
- YAML-based external configuration
- Auditing
- Metrics
- *Lots* of other stuff that comes with stock Spring Boot

So I don't see any reason why I can't use Spring Boot as the underlying framework even though these apps will not be standing up any `@Controllers` or `@RestControllers`.

With Spring Boot, if you don't specify any controllers, it simply starts up and shuts down, because there's nothing to execute. So the question becomes: where do I put my main code that needs to execute? And the two logical places I've thought of are:

1. Right inside the main `@SpringBootApplication`-annotated class where the `main` method is also defined; or, possibly...
2. In an `ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent>` implementation

I'm wondering if there is a **right/wrong** approach here. I guess I just don't know enough about the Spring/Boot lifecycle (and the complicated order of events that things execute in) to know which is correct.

For instance, what if it takes Spring Boot a certain amount of time to fire up properly, but I put my code all inside of the main `@SpringBootApplication`-annotated class and it executes in a few seconds, and prompts Spring to shut down before its even properly finished starting up fully? So I guess the question comes down to this, does one use:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
        new MyApp().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        // put all the app code in here?
    }
}
```

**Or**, something like:

```
@Component
public class StartupListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent event) {
        // put all the app code in here?
    }
}
```

Considerations of either approach? Does Spring Boot offer anything better than either of these solutions, perhaps, something specifically intended for short-lived/ephemeral applications?

Comment: I've normally use ContextStartedEvent, since it is clearer, but you can literally just make a bean, and that will also run at startup. I'd avoid your first suggestion.

Comment: What you are doingin your main won't work and is actually useless. You are creating a spring boot application, ignore it an new an instance of a class. Create a class that implements `CommandLineRunner` or `ApplicationRunner` which will exeute right after everything has been setup. Implement that to exeecute what you want to do. After that finishes (and it doesn't include the `spring-boot-starter-web`) it will shutdown afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, I think you have a typo though ("exeecute" instead of "execute").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just regurgitating M. Deinum's answer above so that I can mark this as answered.

You can use either [`CommandLineRunner` or `ApplicationRunner`](https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-commandlinerunner-and-applicationrunner-example).